# How to Change the Operating System Language

Tags: windows-xp

I have an Italian Version of Windows XP installed on a laptop. I need to change the language to English. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless this is a multi-language version of Windows, you'll have to reinstall with the English version.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I was hoping there was a way other than this.

Answer (score 0):

From an english version of Windows you can apply language pack over it, but only from an english version.

In your case you'll have to reinstall it from scratch, sorry for you.